# symbol file not loaded in VS2017 only happens 10% of the time with JAGPDF

Tags: c++, pdf, visual-studio-2017

[image]I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I have a very simple program to generate a PDF using JAGPDF. If i am opening the program from visual studio (same input, same parameters) it runs to the end without errors 90% of the time, but sometimes it throws an exception  telling me that symbols not loaded for jagpdf-1.4.dll

If I run the executable directly, 90% it creates the PDF correctly and 10% of the time created a corrupted pdf that I cannot open. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I put a screenshot of the error I'm getting, it is very dificult to reproduce because the program runs normally about 90% of the time, so I have to press build several times until it crashes...

EDIT 2: Since it seems the bug is from the library, (I already send them a message reporting it but doubt they'll do something about it because last release was years ago).

I sort of solved the problem by wrapping the function around a loop using try and catch where if the first time it fails then the exception is caught and the function is tried again until it passes.  I put a limit of 10 times it can run the loop before terminating it.

The thinking was that, as the events seem to be statistically independent, the loop will reduce the chance of it failing from 0.1 to 0.1^n with n the number of loops.

So now the program is crashing with a probability of 0.0000001% instead of 10%.

With this fix I am happy to report no fails for this weeks data.

Thank you all for pointing me to the direction of the error.

Comment: ***but sometimes it throws an exception*** Exception for no symbols? I thought that was just a warning in the output window. Since the lack of symbols does not effect your ability to run a program. I think whatever exception you have is not due to the missing symbols. Symbols are important if you think you have found a bug in the library or want to debug your programs interaction with a compiled binary.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I just added more information, if you want me to post all the code I can do so because when I tried a minimal pdf creation process it runs all the time.

Comment: The exception is an Access Violation in the `jagpdf-1.4.dll` dll. Could be a bug in that dll or caused by Undefined Behavior in your code. That has nothing to do with the symbols not loaded. The symbols not loaded prevent you from looking into the dll to see the variable and other names in the disassembly at the address of the crash.

Comment: Thank you, so I was looking in the wrong place... this is bad news because I have no idea how to debug this one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds as if you have found a bug in the PDF library you are using.  You have to file a bug report with the PDF software provider. Hopefully they can provide you support.